# Drupal Views Relationships

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, relationships

I have the following problem:

I created content type "movies" and content type "actors". I added a node reference to the "actors" which links to movies. When i create new actor content I'm able to select movie from node reference. So, I created a list inside Views which shows you a list of actors and next to the actor it displays one of the movies they were in. I did this through node reference in "actors".

Ok, so here is the problem. I now want to create a list of movies and actor next to the movie. I know I can solve this problem if I create another node reference inside movies and every time I create movie content I would need to select actors attached to the movie. Is there a way to do what I need without creating another node reference. I want to use already existing node reference inside actors and show actor depending on the movie selected for the actor.

Can some one please help me with this problem? Im really stuck.

Thank You,
Toliy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [nodereferrer](http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer) module to provide a counterpart to the node reference fields. It makes node references accessible in both directions so you can do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out about [this](http://drupal.org/project/relation), which handles bidirectional relations.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had a lot of success with the [Corresponding Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/cnr)

After you set up your two node references, you can use simple checkboxes to ensure that they are linked up.